# Why didn't Kirk (and crew) simply transport from Earth to Kronos?

Tags: star-trek, movie, star-trek-into-darkness

After his attack on Starfleet HQ, Khan escaped to Kronos using a portable transporter device. This is a device apparently based on Scotty's transwarp teleportation formula he devised in the previous movie.

**Why did Kirk have to fly to Kronos in a ship instead of just transporting there?**

Comment: "After his attack on Starfleet HQ, Khan escaped to Kronos using a portable teleportation device." Wait wait wait wait wait...let me get this straight...they can teleport from Earth to Kronos now?

Comment: @Bobby Yes. Yes they can. Oh wait, you mean this question is a spoiler? Hm.

Comment: @MrLister: No, I meant that I'll sit in a corner and start crying about what Abrams did to Star Trek...and when I did some more crying, I'll get my pitchfork or something. ... But yes, it is a spoiler, but I don't see a point in setting the whole question into spoiler tags.

Comment: Note: In Star Trek, the "teleporter" is called a [Transporter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_(Star_Trek)).  (Unless Abrams decided to change it and I blanked it out)

Comment: @Bobby: In his defence, the technology for transwarp transporters did very explicitly come from quite some time into the future. He didn't so much change the rules as bring future tech back into the past, regular transporters still have the same limitations. Though, of course, they conveniently forget about transwarp beaming as soon as the first movie ends.

Comment: @Phoshi: I don’t think they forgot about it exactly, but it was quickly whisked away by Section 31 and put out of reach of the kids. Didn’t Scotty say something along the lines of Starfleet confiscating the equation from him?

Comment: @alexwlchan: They did indeed, though unless it was destroyed in the subsequent large explosions it seems odd that nobody even considered using it. Okay, so it's now classified, but... you're about to head into Klingon space with classified missiles, so why not at least ask?

Comment: @Phoshi: I think Scotty shows the device in question to Kirk, which he recovered from the wreckage. I’d write not asking off to Kirk being blinded by anger and vengeance, and not thinking to use that or to ask. (Also, how likely are you to capture somebody who can take out a Klingon patrol on home turf, single-handedly?)

Comment: Also, just because you can transport a great distance doesn't mean you can see what will be there when you arrive.  They wouldn't know what they were getting in to on Kronos, so transporting would not be a feasible option.

Comment: @BBlake Unless they just transported a whole bunch of bombs...  Like, y'know, those new torpedoes the Admiral wanted to get rid of?

Comment: I canna hold her captain, thae rampant plot-holes willnae take thae strain!

Comment: I felt that my answer pretty much nailed this one. Is there anything additional you'd want addressing before you consider an acceptance?

Answer (score 13):

Admiral Marcus wanted to start a war with the Klingons. That is why he had Kirk take the advanced photon torpedoes. Additionally, that is why Admiral Marcus sabotaged the Enterprise, so it would break down just inside Klingon space. A Federation ship in Klingon space launching torpedoes at the Klingon home world would be sure to start that war.

Had Kirk et. al. just transported there then there would be no guarantee that that war would happen.

Comment: Admiral was directly going to attack Klingons with USS Vengeance. I don't think, this needs any of Enterprise's action.

Comment: @SachinShekhar The Admiral didn't warp the Vengeance to where the Enterprise was until after the Enterprise had contacted Starfleet about having taken Kahn into custody. Admiral Marcus didn't want to reveal the new dreadnought until it was necessary, as strictly speaking it wasn't supposed to exist.

Comment: Enterprise didn't fire torpedoes, but still Admiral was going to attack Klingons. This says that Enterprise was never intented to make plot of war. Killing Khan was main point (that's why Admiral jumped to Enterprise from his primary course). So, my answer is correct.

Comment: Admiral Marcus was *not* going to attack the Klingons when he flew the Vengeance out to the Enterprise. See my earlier response. He wanted Kirk to fire at Q'onos, their warp drive to break down and the Klingons to destroy the Enterprise before anyone in Starfleet found out what was happening. This would make it look like the Kligons were the aggressors which would have given Marcus legitimate and authorized use of the Vengeance to counter attack. Marcus couldn't risk Kirk finding out from Kahn what his real plan was. **That** is why Marcus went out there.

Comment: That seems to be Admiral Marcus's motive, but why would Kirk go along with it. Neither he or anyone else even suggest that they use a transporter to follow Khan.

Comment: @SystemDown Well, the problem with Kirk or any other Starfleet officer beaming there is that they wouldn't have have any way to get back. Marcus didn't suggest it because his plan to make the Klingons look like the aggressors wouldn't work if the Klingons had one or more Starfleet officers to show as evidence of a Starfleet invasion on Q'onos.

Answer (score 1):

This was addressed in the film's official novelisation. In short, transporting that kind of distance would be *almost certainly fatal* for an ordinary human and *probably fatal* to a Vulcan. Even if they found a group of volunteers dumb enough to risk near-certain death, on arrival they'd be in no fit state to apprehend Khan. Also, they'd be behind enemy lines with absolutely no way of escaping.

Additionally, the power usage required was sufficient to practically destroy the ship that Khan used, meaning that the trans-warp transporter would be pretty useless even if they waited until they were closer to Kronos before using it.

> *"According to Mr. Scott, that transporter was employed to relay him to
> an unmanned vessel in orbit around the moon. Subsequent inspection
> revealed that another unauthorized transwarp device had been placed on
> it and wired into the empty ship’s engine. **A device powerful enough,
> if its entire energy output was compiled and utilized for a single
> massive burst, to send someone willing to take the risk of attenuated
> physical dissemination and consequent serious injury to a single
> destination anywhere in this galactic region.** The effort burned out
> the device, but a record of the attempt was retained.” Kirk paused.
>
> “Mathematically, at least, it appears to have been successful.”*
>
> *“Very clever,” Spock could not keep from commenting. **“It would take an
> exceptionally robust human to survive such a radical transporting.
> Even a Vulcan would be stressed. But if successful, the perpetrator
> would be safe. Burning itself out with the effort, the transwarp
> device could not be used by anyone to follow.”.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek Into Darkness - Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness_(novel))</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

You know, I always took it as the portable transporter requiring a unit set on Kronos to transport to that way you would know exactly where on the planet it was you were arriving at.  Figured since Khan had been MIA for a while, he traveled there, placed the unit and came back to finish the rest of his plan.  Why Kronos though?  Because he knew the actions that Star Fleet and Admiral Marcus would take.  The entire movie was his well layed plan based upon the predictable nature of his opposition.  It wasn't until Kirk and Spock acted unpredictably, ie doing what the other would do, that it all unraveled for him.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran some numbers. A subspace signal takes 15 hours to go from earth to kronos. I transporter signal can only last 7 minutes before it degrades. Although in my reading if a signal is amplified it travels faster but he'd have to access federation subspace arrays

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy, and thanks for posting. Some things about this answer are a bit unclear, though. What model did you use to run these numbers? How do you know, for example, the decay time of a transporter signal? Some citations, and possibly a description of your calculations, would be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Its not clear whether starfleet was able to arrange such long-range teleportation at that point of time or not.

Even if they were capable of such teleportation, they needed to kill Khan without entering Klingon space. The special torpedoes were meant to do it silently.
Enterprise was needed there to fire those torpedoes. And, you can't teleport Enterprise because many complex things like warp core couldn't be teleported.

This was the official plan. So, this is the answer irrespective of admiral's background plan.

Comment: There was no "official plan" Any action taken by the Federation publicly would have been construed as an act of war against the Klingon Empire.  That's why only the Enterprise was sent (so as to look like a rogue captain out for vengeance without the consent of the Federation) Kirk was supposed to go to Kronos fire the torpedoes and go home (but, secretly having been sabotaged, be destroyed and allow all out war with the Klingons)

Comment: @Monty129 What was the official purpose of special torpedoes then?

Comment: There was no "official purpose" they where developed by Section 31 in secret, they weren't intended to be used publicly.  The whole mission was a black ops, off the books one, to allow for Admiral Marcus to disavow Kirk's actions should it come to that.

Comment: @Monty129 Then, answer this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37246/why-didnt-kirk-question-the-admirals-order

Comment: You already have an answer to your question (and it's the correct answer) I would just be re-hashing what Andy already said.

Comment: @Monty129 `Any action taken by the Federation publicly would have been construed as an act of war against the Klingon Empire.` and Andy's answer aren't compatible..

Comment: No they aren't.  Officially Kirk and the Enterprise where acting alone, without approval of the Federation.  The fact that the torpedoes did not exist officially was how they where able to use them in the first place.